# how to sed spacial character if it come inside double quote in linux file

Tags: linux, sed

I have txt file delimited by comma (,) and each column quoted by double quote

what I want to do is :
I need to keep the delimiter as comma but I want to remove each comma come into double pair quote (as each column around by double quote)

sample on input and output file I want

input file :

```
"2022111812160156601777153","","","false","test1",**"here the , issue , that comma comma come inside the column"**
```

the output as I want :

```
"2022111812160156601777153","","","false","test1",**"here the  issue  that comma comma come inside the column"**
```

what I try :

```bash
sed -i ':a' -e 's/\("[^"]*\),\([^"]*"\)/\1~\2/;ta' test.txt
```

but above sed command replace all comma not only the comma that come inside the column

is there are way to do it ?

Comment: Use a CSV parser

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ei.bak ':a;s/((^|,)(\*+)?"[^"]*),/\1/;ta' input_file
"2022111812160156601777153","","","false","test1",**"here the  issue  that comma comma come inside the column"**
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `**` are not really part of the data, and just used for empasis.

Comment: @tripleee yup. Hence why I made its presence optional as OP also shows it in his output expectation

Answer (score 0):

Any time you find yourself using more than `s`, `g`, and `p` (with `-n`) in sed you'd be better off using awk for some combination of clarity, robustness, efficiency, portability, etc.

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/,/,"",$i)} 1' file
"2022111812160156601777153","","","false","test1",**"here the  issue  that comma comma come inside the column"**
```

Just like GNU sed has `-i` as in your question to update the input file with the command's output, GNU awk has `-i inplace`, or just add `> tmp && mv tmp file` with any awk or any other Unix command.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^(("[^",]*"\**,?\**)*"[^",]*),/\1/;ta' file
```

This iterates through each line removing any commas within paired double quoted fields.

N.B. The solution above also caters for double quoted field prefixed/suffixed by zero or `*`'s. If this should not be catered for, here is an ameliorated solution:

```
 sed -E ':a;s/^(("[^",]*",?)*"[^",]*),/\1/;ta' file
```

N.B. Escaped double quotes and commas would need a or more involved regexp.